# Unable to set the background color value from json in to the HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm new to the JavaScript. I have a html page which is binded with 'Bind_script.js'. In the `Bind_script.js`, I'm setting the background color of the span id from a function `update_BG` which takes span id as a parameter. I am trying to parse sapn id from the JSON file.

When I invoke the function `update_BG()` with a hard coded value, the span id background color get changed, but when I pass the same value from the parsed JSON, it is not working as expected.

## 1 HTML Page

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    .Table
    {
        display: table;
    }
    .Title
    {
        display: table-caption;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    .Heading
    {
        display: table-row;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .Row
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
</style>

<head>
<script src ="Bind_script.js">
</script>
</head>    
<body>
<h1>"The dns ip is: " <span id="myID"></span></h1>

    <div class="Heading">
        <div Class="Cell">
            <p>G</p>
        </div>
        <div Class="Cell">
            <p>facebook.com</p>
        </div>
        <div id="test">
            <span id="h" class="Cell">
                <p>H</p>
            </span>
            <span id="e" class="cell">
                <p>E</p>
            </span>
           <span id ="Time" class="Cell">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
        </div>


        <div Class="Cell">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>


</html>
```

## 2 Json File

```
{

  "ABC.com":["h","e"],
  "BCD.com":["e","h"],
  "CDE.com":["h","e"]

}
```

## 3 javascript

```
const fs = require('fs')

function update_BG(col) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('All assets are loaded')
  document.getElementById(col).style.background = "green";
})
}
//update_BG("e")
let rawData= fs.readFileSync("C:/example.json");

let url = JSON.parse(rawData);
 //var value= url['ABC.com'][1]
 update_BG("e")
```

Expected:
I need to set the background color of the Span ID according to the value that parsed from the json file

Actual:
The background color is not setting according to the value from the json

Appreciate if anyone can help on this?

Comment: You are confusing client-side JS with server-side node JS. `const fs = require('fs')` won't work in a browser. And accessing the user's hard drive like that would be a massive security hole. What you can do is a) let the user select the file via `<input type="file">`, then read it with a FileReader object. Or b) you put the JSON on the server, request it via `fetch()` and read it.

Comment: You cannot perform filesystem reads in a browser. You need to perform an XMLHttpRequest (or a `fetch()`) to load data that is not included in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG, i understood the issue now as you said. So the script should included in the HTML page itself without binding it from externally. Could  you please give with any example for my case?  Thank You

Comment: I don't know that you actually understood... you cannot read JSON files from the browser as it is on the user's machine, not your server. you would need to make an Ajax call for the JSON data from the server, then process it in the browser. I would encourage you to research how to make Ajax calls from from the browser to your server.

Comment: There are some workarounds - you can use Ajax in local page in FF if you enable it in FF settings or you can include JSON in your page in a frame or iframe or as script if it will start with variable assignment. But again small catch IE load scripts in a random order by default, so hard to be sure sometimes if dependencies were loaded yet.

Comment: Whether you put the JS commands in a script tag or use the tag to link to an external script doesn't matter; you cannot use `fs` either way. If you want to change background colors on a web page based on a JSON file, you need to use one of the methods we described. And you can of course always put the contents of the JSON file in your script, as object literal: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/L196u7qr/

Comment: Thank You @jakerella and all other members for your inputs. This got worked when i parse the value through AJAX call